# How can the "Process" action be programmatically clicked on the POCreate page?

Tags: acumatica

I know that typically one would call the action name and the Press() function, however there is no actions object or PXButton function in the code for the Process button on the POCreate page. I tried to access the function that may perform the action, but I'm unable to access them either.

Is there a special method to activate the Process action on this page through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call the process from another screen and just call CreatePOOrders in POCreate. The process delegate is wired to CreateProc which calls CreatePOOrders. No need to call the action for process if you call the static call it is wired to.

Its static and public and takes the list of entries you want to process.

```
public static PXRedirectRequiredException CreatePOOrders(List<POFixedDemand> list, DateTime? PurchDate, bool extSort)
```

Keep in mind you might need to set the VendorID for the POFixedDemand objects to correctly create the purchase order. Same fields you would need to have entered in the Create Purchase Order screen for the process to work.

If you have an instance of the graph you really want to use you can call the process by calling Actions["myactionname"].Press() such as this example:

```
var pograph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POCreate>();
// set pograph.FixedDemand
pograph.Actions["Process"].Press();
```

For process all use "ProcessAll" in place of "Process". During debug you can look at your graph instance Actions collection to get the name of the action you should use in the example above.

Comment: I'm accessing the graph via PXGraph.CreateInstance<>(). Is there a way to access this function via the object created via that function?

Comment: No since that call is static and within the call it is working with the POOrderEntry graph. If you need anything special beyond that you might need to modify POOrderEntry or add in event handlers to the POOrderEntry graph when calling the POCreate static call. What else would you need an instance for? related to how you are building your POFixedDemand objects?

Comment: You would just use POCreate.CreatePOOrders(...)

Comment: Updated answer to include the press of the process action

Comment: Thanks Brendan, I'll try it. I started down that route actually and was going to ask you about using POCreate.CreatePOOrders() function.

Comment: Since the action calls that method i thing its just easier to use the static method vs the action but both should work. Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Just letting you know that calling the function, POCreate.CreatePOOrders() function worked better than calling the action. When I called the action, I got this error: Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Data.PXProcessingInfo`1[PX.Objects.PO.POFixedDemand]' to type 'PX.Data.PXProcessingInfo`1[PX.Data.GenericResult]'. I'm not sure what caused the error, but I'm not concerned about it.

Comment: Maybe that is why we didn't use the action too. It has been a while since we implemented this. Usually I try to call a method that the action uses if possible. Good to see you got it working.